# Can I change selected bone through Graph Editor

Tags: animation, selection-tools, graph-editor

I need to edit animation on several bones in while viewing them in the Graph Editor, to extend my animation.

Firstly, yes: I am familiar with a workflow like GE *Key >> Insert >> ... at Cursor*, but this doesn't help be review limits and "play" with values in an efficient way.

My desired workflow follows...

I start in Pose Mode by Selecting-All (bones), to investigate which bone Poses are already animated in Dope & GE.   I want to add/extend cycles mods or add additional movement to these.

I focus on an F-Curve to edit, but I then have to Expand all Channels in the View and scroll around to find which is highlighted.

[image]

I would now like to select this Bone/Channel, but cannot do this in GE:

[image]

This would allow me to investigate rotation limits to experiment with:

[image]

and animate in the 3D View, looking at the desired effect:

[image]

Alas, there is no way do this without hunting through the boned list in the Outliner:

[image]

Am I overlooking a nifty way to select this bone via the G.E.?   Or would this be a feature request (or write a custom script to add to the GE Select menu)?